# Resampling Rows minute wise not working in for Even Minutes in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have df which has 5 columns. A column named date which has minute-wise data of a few days but the data start at `9:15` and ends at `15:29`. And then there are four other columns which are named first, max, min, and last which have numerical numbers in them.

I wrote a code that uses `x` mins as a variable. It resamples the rows and gives rows of x minutes.

The first of resampled will be the 'first' of first row. 
The 'last' of resampled will be the 'last' of the last row. 
The max of resampled will be the highest of all the rows of the max column. 
The low of resampled will be low of all the rows for the low column.
And the date will have datetime of x minutes intervals.

My problem is for some minutes the code is working perfectly. But for other minutes I am getting the wrong time as the first row.

Instead of resampled data starting from `9:15`. It starts with some other minute.

Code:

```
def resample_df(df, x_minutes = '15T'):
    
    df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

    resampled_df = df.resample(x_minutes).agg({
        'first': 'first',
        'max': 'max',
        'min': 'min',
        'last': 'last'
    })

    resampled_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    return resampled_df
```

Input:

```
    date                   first    max         min         last
0   2023-06-01 09:15:00 0.014657    0.966861    0.556195    0.903073
1   2023-06-01 09:16:00 0.255174    0.607714    0.845804    0.039933
2   2023-06-01 09:17:00 0.956839    0.881803    0.876322    0.552568
```

Output: when x_minutes = '6T'

```
    date                   first    max         min         last
0   2023-06-01 09:12:00 0.014657    0.966861    0.556195    0.552568
1   2023-06-01 09:18:00 0.437867    0.988005    0.162957    0.897419
2   2023-06-01 09:24:00 0.296486    0.370957    0.013994    0.108506
```

The data shows 9:12 but I don't have 9:12. Why is it giving me the wrong data?

Note: It works prefectly when minutes entered are odd. e.g. x_minutes = '15T'

Code to create a dummy df:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define the number of days for which data is generated
num_days = 5

# Define the start and end times for each day
start_time = datetime.strptime('09:15', '%H:%M').time()
end_time = datetime.strptime('15:30', '%H:%M').time()

# Create a list of all the timestamps for the specified days
timestamps = []
current_date = datetime.now().replace(hour=start_time.hour, minute=start_time.minute, second=0, microsecond=0)
end_date = current_date + timedelta(days=num_days)
while current_date < end_date:
    current_time = current_date.time()
    if start_time <= current_time <= end_time:
        timestamps.append(current_date)
    current_date += timedelta(minutes=1)

# Generate random data for each column
data = {
    'date': timestamps,
    'first': [random.random() for _ in range(len(timestamps))],
    'max': [random.random() for _ in range(len(timestamps))],
    'min': [random.random() for _ in range(len(timestamps))],
    'last': [random.random() for _ in range(len(timestamps))]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
display(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
resampled_df = df.resample(x_minutes, origin = 'start').agg({
    'first': 'first',
    'max': 'max',
    'min': 'min',
    'last': 'last'
})
```

Comment: To add more detail to the answer, "start" will start from the first timestamp in the index.  See [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#:~:text=be%20datetime%2Dlike.-,originTimestamp,-or%20str%2C%20default) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'll check and let you know.